# How do I check my dropdowns and the corresponding vlookup quickly?

Tags: microsoft-excel, speed

When I click into a dropdown in Excel I have a list of options that i can highlight through, but until I click the option the vlookup formula (which looks up the description and price) doesn't update. Is there a way to quickly cycle through options in a dropdown and select and then move to the next one? I might be out on a limb here.

Comment: Would you be open to having the result of the `VLOOKUP` displayed as part of the option in the dropdown? This can be done, but I'm not sure about what you've specifically asked for.

Comment: If you use a combobox (editable field with dropdown) instead of a dropdown you can generally use the up/down arrow keys to scroll through the contents and have the quick updates you're looking for.

Comment: @MikeFitzpatrick Maybe I'm missing something obvious but isn't a dropdown just a `combo box`? (Ok, data validation with list as source also creates dropdowns and auto filter too. But I doubt that OP means those types). Do you mean `List box` instead?

Comment: @nixda, in Excel 2010 when I hover over the forms control the tool tip says it is a `Combo Drop-Down Edit (Form Control)`. Strangely, it is greyed out at the moment so I haven't verified its behaviour.